# I am trying to validate my data using data validation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have list of data in current stock sheet and i want to check if user's entered value match with one of value of the list. Suppose current stock sheet has 16.001,15.002,15.0089 etc. and i want to check if users entered value match with one of the listed value in current stock or not. my range in both the sheet is dynamic. I am getting run-time error 424.

```
       ' my current sheet is consumption(wc)
     Option Explicit

 Public i As Integer
 Public wc As Worksheet
 Public ws As Worksheet


Sub consumption()

Dim counter As Integer
Dim erow As Integer, counterrun As Integer
Dim result As Integer, result1 As Integer, loopresult As Integer
Dim user As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("current stock")

Set wc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("consumption")
erow = wc.Cells(wc.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1

counter = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter a counter:", Type:=1)
For i = erow To counterrun

  Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Entre a Dwg No.", Type:=2)
Call getCodeFromUser

End Sub


Function getCodeFromUser() As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim platecode As Integer ' my platecode is like 16.0012

Do
    platecode = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter a code", Type:=1)

  Set rng = ws.Range("C4:C25860").Find(What:=platecode, LookAt:=xlWhole) ' error 91 occurs here.

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function  ' if platecode is not from rng  i want to exit
   With rng.Validation
.Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & rng.Address ' yes i want to go back to my sub when value is correct


If rng Is Nothing Then ' what do you suggest instead of this If?

        MsgBox "Somthing is wrong with " & platecode
    End If

End With


Loop Until platecode = True ' i want to run this loop till values are match
Cells(i, 4).Value = platecode ' stored location. it will save value of platecode if it is true.
' value of "i" is taken from public
End Function
```

Comment: you have `Function getCodeFromUser() As Variant` in the middle of your `Sub consumption()` ? where is your `End Sub` ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Actually it is not complete code so i forgot to mention it. @shai Rado

Comment: Also the var `code` is never defined neither `true` or `false`, and yet you want to loop until its `false`. The default value for Boolean variables is `false`, which will cause it not to loop, because its already `false`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, it's just too long to put as a comment.

Read the slightly modified code below, and see my comments (especially the ones with `?` , where it indicates where you have an error).

**Note**: as good coding practice, always use `Option Explicit` in the beginning of your code, when you try to **Compile VBAProject** you will get an error, and the curser will point to all the lines where you have variables which have not been properly defined.

**Temp. modified code**

```
Option Explicit 

' Public variables definition section
Public Platecode As Integrer
Public code as Boolean ' <-- not the greateset variable name
Public ws As Worksheet     

'==============================================================

Sub consumption()

Dim counter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
'Dim ws As Worksheet ' <-- remove from here, define as Public
Dim wc As Worksheet
Dim rangs As Range, rangc As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("current stock")
Set wc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("consumption")

Call getCodeFromUser 

End Sub

'==================================================================

Function getCodeFromUser As Variant

Dim Rng As Range

Do
    Platecode = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter a code", Type:=1) ' where is Platecode defined or set ?

    Set Rng = ws.Range("c4:c128").Find(What:=Platecode, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' <-- you want to exit the function if Find was Successful ?

    With ws.Cells(i, 4).Validation ' < where is i defined or set ?
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & rangs.Address ' <-- where is rangs defined or set ?

        If ws.Cells(i, 4) Is Nothing Then ' <-- this If doesn't need to be nested inside the 'With' above
            MsgBox "Something is wrong with " & ws.Cells(i, 4).value
        End If
    End With
Loop Until code = False ' where is code defined ? where do you reset it?

End Function
```

Comment: Can i recall values from sub?  Because platecode and "i" are define in sub and value of "i" is dependent user's entered counter value. I think you will be more clear after i show you full code. I will do that as soon as possibles. I am extremely sorry for this delay and thank you for pointing out mistakes.

Comment: @divy.h you could do that, but then you have to define these variables outside the `Sub` level, but in the module level, right after `Option Explicit`, and define each one of them as `Public` (look at updated code above)

Comment: I have change my code as you suggested and answered your question. Please check my edited code.@Shai Rado